# How to modify pattern of dashed line to not start/end with a space?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I force the pattern of a dashed line to be shifted/modified in such way that it **does not** start/end with a space?

Simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw coordinate (nw) (0,0) rectangle (4,4) coordinate(se);
\path (nw)--coordinate (aux) (se); 
\draw[dashed] (nw|-aux)--(aux-|se);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the resulting output the line ends with a space.

[image: 4]

If `se` is at `(3,3)` the line both starts and ends with no space:

[image: 3]

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203442/dash-pattern-that-starts-with-space

Comment: @Ignasi I already saw that question, how would it work with the additional constraint to have a solid end?

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133271/can-tikz-dashed-lines-emulate-pstricks-dashed-lines) for another related discussion.

Comment: @MarkWibrow thanks, I tried it, it works. I will close this question as a duplicate.